# Running a function through a submit button

Tags: django

I have the following code which runs a function, at the moment the function runs when the webpage is loaded, I need the function to run when the form is submitted. It's a temporary fix which will work for now. Is a form the best way to handle this, I'm open to suggestions.

Should I use javascript in some way?

```
    <form class="" action="." method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% function1 %}
      <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Run</button>
    </form>
```

Edit

I'm using templatetags to hold the raw sql, which is needed because I'm connecting to multiple systems. It is temporary and within a sealed system (before concerns are raised regarding sql injection etc).

```
@register.simple_tag
def update_new_rows():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(""" <SQL code> """ )
```

In the template tags are loaded but the sql runs when the page is loaded, I only want the sql code to run when the button is pressed.

Comment: Why not in the view?

Comment: Going through a view was the correct way to do it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use onSubmit method to do that so your code should be like that  :

```
<form class="" action="." method="post" onSubmit="doSomething(this)">
```

Comment: I've updated the question - see the edit - I've tried this but including `{% function1 %}` in the onSubmit or value, or action does not stop it being run when the page is loaded.